# Formulas for sequences and then how to find the limsup and liminf

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

For each of the following sequences, calculate the limit superior and the limit inferior. If the sequence converges, calculate its limit. Justify your answers.

A) $\ \ \left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3},-\frac{2}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},-\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{5},\frac{4}{5},-\frac{4}{5},\ldots\right\}$.

B) $\ \ \left\{\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{8},\frac{1}{7},\ldots\right\}$.

I can calculate the *inf* and *sup* of equations but *lim inf* and *lim sup* confuse me as well as finding the formulas for these sequences.

Answer (score 0):

A) Limes superior is $1$, limes inferior is $-1$.

The important subsequence for proving *lim sup* is

$$a_n =\left\{\frac{1}{2},\frac{2}{3},\frac{3}{4},\frac{4}{5},\ldots\right\}$$

as its limit is $1$, and for every its element are two previous elements in the original sequence smaller.

For *lim inf* the reasoning is similar - with the subsequence

$$b_n =\left\{-\frac{2}{3}, -\frac{3}{4},-\frac{4}{5},-\frac{5}{6},\ldots\right\}$$

B) limit of this sequence is $0$ - it is just a "masked" sequence

$$\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{5},\frac{1}{6},\frac{1}{7},\frac{1}{8},\ldots\right\}$$

with swapped pairs of adjacent members. So *lim sup* and *lim inf* are both $0$, too.

Comment: This explains alot but how would i justufy my answer? is it just elementary through statements or just looking?

Comment: Ad A): *lim sup* of subsequence is $\leq$ *lim sup* of original sequence, and I showed, that < is not possible. -  Ad B): *If subsequences of odd elements and even elements of the same sequence have the same limit, then the sequence itself has that limit, too (trivial).* But they both have limit $0$ as they themselves are subsequences of the "unmasked" harmonic sequence,